# Vertically Center Text in A Button for Android Kotlin

Tags: android, button, text, center

Trying to vertically center text inside a Button. I have set the gravity to center vertical :

android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical

And this works fine for the standard fonts. However, for unique fonts, specifically for "@font/bangers", the text in the button is not vertically centered - it's off vertically quite a noticeable bit.

Is there another attribute (line spacing and line height don't seem to do the trick) that needs to be updated to set fonts that may have different type settings?

Answer (score 0):

I once faced that too in one of my test projects. I set the `android:layout_height="warp_content"` and did the trick with `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom`.